# Positioning of Kendo UI RangeSlider ToolTip

Tags: kendo-ui, slider

I am using a `RangeSlider`, and would like to position the tooltip below the slider, not above.

```
  $('#tollerance_slider').kendoRangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 300,
    tooltip: {
      position: "bottom"
      }
    });
```

that doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a setting you can give it because it does not use the normal Kendo Tooltip widget internally (slider is probably an older widget that was written before Tooltip).

However, you can do it with CSS:

```
.k-widget.k-tooltip.k-slider-tooltip {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```